# How can I set virtual attributes in the mongoid search gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a hard time with the `mongoid_search` gem on a few fronts and I wonder if it is working properly. As per the instructions, I am trying to create virtual attributes so that I can search on custom keywords that I create. Here are the instructions from the web page.

> You can also search in "virtual" fields by defining them as methods. This can be useful when you have a method with dynamic fields (i.e. variable schema)

```
class ModelWithDynamicFields
  
  ...
  
  search_in :search_data

  def search_data
    # concatenate all String fields' values
    self.attributes.select{|k,v| v.is_a?(String) }.values.join(' ')
  end
end
```

> Mongoid_search will run the method before save and use it's output to populate the _keywords field.

I've found that this is not the case and Im trying to find outif I am doing something wrong or if there may be a problem with the gem.

Here is my code.

```
class User
   search_in :search_data

  def search_data
    ["#{self.attributes["email_address"]}", "#{self.attributes["first_name"]}", "#{self.attributes["last_name"]}"]
  end
```

What I want the output to be in the `_keywords` array is the output of my virtual search_data method which should be this

```
[allanj@gmail.com allan jones]
```

This should be the EXACT keywords array that I want yet, the gem keeps ignoring the output of this code and goes to the default behavior. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: I don’t know that gem but the example code returns a string whereas your code returns an array. Maybe it only supports strings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment stefan. It does look to be the case that you can set an array directly like this or a string, which makes this matter even more confusing.

Comment: A quick test worked for me just fine with both, strings and arrays. Can you provide a [mre] that I can run on my machine?